# NodeJS calculate its sum for specific date from JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, nodes

I am new in NodeJS and I am learning on how to calculate the data,

Consider the JSON data from the url is like this and there are about 100 data.

```
[{
    "ID": "01",
    "sales": 11,
    "points": 5,
    "date": "2019-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"
},
{
    "ID": "02",
    "sales": 25,
    "points": 15,
    "date": "2022-05-23T18:25:43.511Z"
},
.
.
.
{
    "ID": "12",
    "sales": 20,
    "points": 11,
    "date": "2022-05-23T18:25:43.511Z"
},
{
    "ID": "01",
    "sales": 50,
    "points": 30,
    "date": "2023-11-23T18:25:43.511Z",
},
{
    "ID": "01",
    "sales": 40,
    "points": 30,
    "date": "2021-07-23T18:25:43.511Z",
}]
```

I want to count how many sales each ID made in between starting date beginning 2021 January until end date December 2023. The result would be somehow like this

```
[{
     "ID": "01",
     "totalsales": 150
},
.
.
.
{
     "ID": "15",
     "totalsales": 300
}]
```

Comment: how do you give your date as input

Comment: Handle this in query level,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it like this:

```js
const jsonData = [{
"ID": "01",
"sales": 11,
"points": 5,
"date": "2019-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"
},
{
"ID": "02",
"sales": 25,
"points": 15,
"date": "2022-05-23T18:25:43.511Z"
},
{
"ID": "12",
"sales": 20,
"points": 11,
"date": "2022-05-23T18:25:43.511Z"
},
{
"ID": "01",
"sales": 50,
"points": 30,
"date": "2023-11-23T18:25:43.511Z",
},
{
"ID": "01",
"sales": 40,
"points": 30,
"date": "2021-07-23T18:25:43.511Z",
}]

const startDate = new Date('2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z');
const endDate = new Date('2024-01-01T00:00:00.000Z');

const result = {}; // Create an empty object to store the result

jsonData.forEach((data) => {
  const date = new Date(data.date);
  const year = date.getUTCFullYear();
  const id = data.ID;

  if (date >= startDate && date <= endDate) { // Check if date is within the specified range
    if (result[id]) {
      result[id].totalsales += data.sales; // Add to existing ID's total sales
    } else {
      result[id] = { ID: id, totalsales: data.sales }; // Create new ID entry with sales data
    }
  }
});

console.log(Object.values(result)); // Print the final result as an array of objects
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pretty easily with the help of with the `reduce` function:

```
const [startDate, endDate] = ["2021-01-01", "2022-01-01"] // eg from 2021 to 2022

// results in an object with the keys being the IDs and the values being their respective sales in the time-period
const salesById = data.reduce((sales, current) => {
  const date = new Date(current.date);
  if (date >= startDate && date <= endDate) {
    const id = current.ID;
    // the current entry is within the time-frame, add it to the accumulator object
    sales[id] = (sales[id] || 0) + current.sales;
  }
  return sales; // continue with the next data entry with all sales-data accumulated so far
}, {});

// Results in your desired format
const formattedResult = Object.keys(salesById).map(ID => ({
  ID,
  totalsales: salesById[ID]
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group the items by `ID`.

This creates an object with a property for each ID, we can then use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the result as an array.

We'll also filter by date, checking that each date is between the start and end dates.

```js
const data = [{ "ID": "01", "sales": 11, "points": 5, "date": "2019-04-23T18:25:43.511Z" }, { "ID": "02", "sales": 25, "points": 15, "date": "2022-05-23T18:25:43.511Z" }, { "ID": "12", "sales": 20, "points": 11, "date": "2022-05-23T18:25:43.511Z" }, { "ID": "01", "sales": 50, "points": 30, "date": "2023-11-23T18:25:43.511Z", }, { "ID": "01", "sales": 40, "points": 30, "date": "2021-07-23T18:25:43.511Z", }]

const startDate = '2021-01-01T00:00:000Z';
const endDate =   '2024-01-01T00:00:000Z';

const result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, { ID, sales, date }) => { 
    if ((date >= startDate) && (date < endDate)) {
        acc[ID] = acc[ID] || { ID, totalSales: 0 };
        acc[ID].totalSales += sales;
    }
    return acc;
}, {}))

console.log('Total sales by ID:')
console.log(result.sort((a,b) => a.ID - b.ID));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```